# Using NSubstitute and Ninject to return a value

Tags: c#, ninject, nsubstitute

In my  `NinjectDependencyResolver: IDependencyResolver`  I have a AddBindings() method that for now I want it to return some hard coded values for me until I connect it to DB later.

The class and interface I want to mock and use in that AddBindings() method are like this:

```
public class Configuration
{
    public string WebSiteNotActiveMessage { get; set; }
    public bool IsWebSiteActive { get; set; }
}

public interface IConfigurationManager
{
    Models.Configuration.Configuration ConfigFileValues { get; }
}
```

Now I wanted to mock the interface and return a value in my Ninject method so I started writing something like this but got stuck, not sure how I should do it:

```
  private void AddBindings()
    {
        var config = Substitute.For<IConfigurationManager>();

        config.ConfigFileValues.IsWebSiteActive = true;
        config.ConfigFileValues.WebSiteNotActiveMessage = "Website is not active!!!";

        // ? 
    }
```

Comment: I think like this?               config.ConfigFileValues.IsWebSiteActive.Returns(true);
            config.ConfigFileValues.WebSiteNotActiveMessage.Returns("Website not active.");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general* NSubstitute will not automatically substitute for members that return classes like `Configuration`, so you'll need to manually stub it:

```
var config = Substitute.For<IConfigurationManager>();
config.ConfigFileValues.Returns(new Configuration());
config.ConfigFileValues.IsWebSiteActive = true;
config.ConfigFileValues.WebSiteNotActiveMessage = "Website is not active!!!";
```

(* the exception being [pure virtual classes](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/auto-and-recursive-mocks/))

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem regarding your interface is that your only property, `ConfigFileValues`, has only a getter. It should have also setter, which would initialize it from the class that would implement the interface. In terms of code that I suggest is this:

```
public interface IConfigurationManager
{
    Models.Configuration.Configuration ConfigFileValues { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: A setter isn't required in this case, and could be detrimental if you do not wish this value to be changed from other classes.