# Why I am getting null exception when using an Interface

Tags: c#

```
public class Blah
{
    public bool Whatever { get; set; }
    public string WhatYouJustSaid { get; set; }
}

public interface IBlah
{
    Blah BlahValues { get; set; }
}

class Class1:IBlah
{
    public Blah BlahValues { get; set; }
}
```

And then for example:

```
   Class1 c1 = new Class1();
   c1.BlahValues.WhatYouJustSaid = "nothing";
    c1.BlahValues.Whatever = false;
```

So how should I change my code that `BlahValues` doesn't get null?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the fact that you're using an interface. You have a property that you you never initialized. Of course it'll be null. You have to assign a value to BlahValues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize the `BlahValues`. Using an object initializer, this can be done as below:

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1()
{
   BlahValues = new Blah() 
};
```

As you create the `c1` object, the `BlahValues` get it's default value, which is `null`. Hence, when you try to assign a value to `WhatYouJustSaid` and `Whatever` you get a null reference exception.

Comment: Can you take a look at this question I had please ? In that question I was using Ninject and NSubstitute and getting a null exception crash which first I thought it is becuase I am new to both of those but then I recreated the way I am using interfaces in this question and got the same null exception. So maybe you can help with my actual question here too ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777185/using-nsubstitute-and-ninject-to-return-a-value

Answer (score 0):

use it like this inside the constructor of Class1

```
public  Class1()
{
    this.BlahValues = new Blah() 
}
```